# Can etc. mean "or something else"?

Tags: meaning

Just saw the definition of word *miss* from some web dictionary, which says "to fail to hit, catch, etc something." I suppose this could be written as "to fail to hit, catch, **or** do something alike something." Does that *etc* mean, technically, "**or** many other things alike"? How? Doesn't *et* mean "and" in Latin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the first part of the phrase `etc` nailed; the rest of it - *cetera* - means "the rest" (from the Latin *cēterus*).  So put together, they mean "and the rest" or "and the remainder" or "and so forth".  The reader should understand that **similar** such things are also included.

However, this is not a *logical* [AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) necessarily, which you were getting at.  Lists containing `etc` are often *suggestive* and not absolutely precise as to their contents.

Comment: -ducks, red things, people with bowling balls, etc.